# Mathjax won't reload when using mithril mount function

Tags: mathjax, mithril.js

I am using Mithril and am dynamically mounting some content.  the first time the page loads everything works fine.  Once I click a button, which causes one thing to unmount and another to mount, the Mathjax won't render again. I have tried calling the `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` function on element and page load, but it still does not work.  The console indicates that `MathJax.Hub` is undefined after the remount.  MathJax itself is being loaded synchronously.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message suggests that you may be using MathJax version 3 rather than version 2.  The MathJax API has changed significantly with version 3, and `MathJax.Hub` is no longer part of version 3.  The replacement you are looking for is probably `MathJax.typesetPromise()`.  See the MathJax documentation for [typesetting and converting math](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html) for more details.